# Using #each to display some data in handlebars.js not displaying

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, handlebars.js

Hi have a project where i'm converting a static website into a datadriven one, for now i am just trying to change so the content of each page is taken into the website through a data object.

I'm using : node.js, handlebars, express

My index.js file has an object like this

```
var item = [{
  pagetitle: 'Page 1',
  text: 'content page 1'
}, {
  pagetitle: 'Page 2',
  text: 'content page 2'
}, {
  pagetitle: 'Page 3',
  text: 'content page 3'
}, {
  pagetitle: 'Page 4',
  text: 'content page 4'
}, {
  pagetitle: 'Page 10',
  text: 'content page 10'
}];
```

my index.hbs looks like this

```
<div class="bb-blah">
  {{title}
  {{#each item}}
  <div class="bb-item" id="item{{@key}}">
     <h2>{{pagetitle}}</h2>
     <div class="cols-2">
         <p>{{text}}</p>
     </div>
  </div>
  {{/each}}
</div>
```

For some reason nothing is displayed on the page like it should be. "item" should iterate item1 item2 item3 to display each page of the website so i need that to increment every time i press my button (this works on the normal website but i can't get it to work with @key. Also the {{pagetitle}} and {{text}} do not display at all on the website.

Comment: When you render the template you have to pass it some data. What data are you passing? I ask b/c you are declaring `var item` but then the template has other properties (like `title`) that are not in the `item` array. Perhaps you just need to feed the template with all of the data contained in one object.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to specify what the `item` property is on the object that you are passing to the template in order for the template to iterate over the items in the `item` array.

When you are rendering the template, pass in the `item` array under the property of `item`. In doing so, your template will see the `item` property and it will iterate over the items as expected.

```
var template = Handlebars.compile(html);
var rendered = template({
  item: item
});
```

The reason there was likely some confusion was because you probably expected the handlebars template to render the `item` variable, despite not being a property on the object that was passed in.

Here is a basic example demonstrating this:

```js
var html = $("#template").html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(html);

var item = [{pagetitle : 'Page 1', text:'content page 1'},
{pagetitle : 'Page 2', text:'content page 2'},
{pagetitle : 'Page 3', text:'content page 3'},
{pagetitle : 'Page 4', text:'content page 4'},
{pagetitle : 'Page 10', text:'content page 10'}];

$('body').append(template({item: item}));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.6/handlebars.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
{{#each item}}
<div class="bb-item" id="item{{@key}}">
   <h2>{{pagetitle}}</h2>
   <div class="cols-2">
       <p>{{text}}</p>
   </div>
</div>
{{/each}}
</script>
```